# Making a textbox unselectable

Tags: asp.net, html

Hi i have a textbox which i am using as a counter to show how many characters are still allowed in another textbox. I have made it read only and its background transparent so that you cant tell it is a select box. The only problem is you can still click on it or tab to it. Is there a way to do this so it appears just like normal text and people cant click on it or tab to it?

Comment: Is there a reason why you have to use a textbox?

Comment: Why don't you use another control, something like a label or a literal. It would be more appropriate. You would still be able to get and set the value both on the client and server side.

Comment: I need it to be able to be constantly changed from a client side function. Also i edited the question it is a html textbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace the `input` element with a `span` element or some other non-input element. This requires a trivial change to your JavaScript; you would assign to the `innerHTML` property of the element rather than `value`. Then the content will appear as normal text, and you can style it as desired.

Answer (score 2):

If this is an [Asp.Net Web Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.aspx) set it's `Enabled` property to `false`

```
<asp:TextBox Enabled="false" />
```

If it is HTML you can do this:

```
<input type="text" disabled />
```

Comment: you can probably not use a textbox for this.

Answer (score 1):

you need some style with css and some trick with Jquery.

**CSS**

```
.readonly{
    border:none;
    background:#aaa;    
}​
```

**Jquery**

```
 $(".readonly").focus(function(){
       $(this).blur();
});​
```

now just add `class="readonly"` to your textbox.

```
<asp:TextBox cssClass="readonly" />
```

check demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/QX9jc/1/) .